# Mac Catalina / Python 3.8.3 / Speech Recognition / Cannot get mic input to VS Code while the code works fine from Terminal

Tags: python, macos, permissions, speech-recognition, macos-catalina

I am trying to work on SpeechRecognition. When I run the code on Visual Stuido Code it doesn't listen, when I run the code from Mac Terminal it receives audio input and works fine... I tired to drag&drop VS to mic permissions. I cannot make it work anyway...

```
def get_audio():
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    said = ""

    try:
        said = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception', str(e))

return said.lower()


print("Speak now!")
print(get_audio())
```